# NotSerializableException with Primefaces/Omnifaces validator on Jboss EAP 6.3 in Mode Cluster

Tags: jsf, serialization, jboss6.x, omnifaces, tag-handler

I'm trying to use Omnifaces's validator in the following lines of code
inside composite component inplementation:

```
<p:inputText id="#{cc.attrs.id}" size="12" maxlength="10" value="#{cc.attrs.holder.idHolderPk}"
    label="#{cc.attrs.label}" styleClass="content-right"
    disabled="#{not empty cc.attrs.disabled?cc.attrs.disabled:false}">
    <f:validator disabled="#{!cc.attrs.required}" validatorId="#{cc.attrs.validatorName}"/>
    <o:validator disabled="#{empty cc.attrs.beanValidation ? true : false}" validatorId="javax.faces.Bean" validationGroups="#{cc.attrs.beanValidation}"/>
    <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{holderHelperBean.findHolder()}"
        process="@this" update="outpnlHolder"
        oncomplete="#{not empty cc.attrs.remoteListener ? cc.attrs.remoteListener : ''}"/>
    <pe:keyFilter mask="pint"/>
</p:inputText>
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR [org.infinispan.transaction.TransactionCoordinator] (ajp-118)     
ISPN000097: Error while processing a prepare in a single-phase transaction: org.infinispan.CacheException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure to marshal argument(s)
    at org.infinispan.util.Util.rewrapAsCacheException(Util.java:542)[0m
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.invokeRemoteCommand(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:186)[0m
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.invokeRemotely(JGroupsTransport.java:515)[0m
    at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.invokeRemotely(RpcManagerImpl.java:173)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.invokeRemotely(RpcManagerImpl.java:194)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.invokeRemotely(RpcManagerImpl.java:251)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.invokeRemotely(RpcManagerImpl.java:238)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.invokeRemotely(RpcManagerImpl.java:233)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure to marshal argument(s)
Caused by: org.infinispan.marshall.NotSerializableException: org.omnifaces.taghandler.Validator
```

I am using Jboss 6.3 EAP in mode cluster with session replication, Omnifaces 1.8.1, Primefaces 4.0.13, Mojarra 2.1.28-jbossorg-5.

I am using o:validator to bean validation because I need dynamic disabled and rendered validation

When application is in standalone mode working fine without error message.

Comment: Those serialization issues were fixed for OmniFaces 2.1 which isn't released yet. Before posting an answer, can you give the current `2.1-SNAPSHOT` a try and confirm if that indeed also solves your problem?

Comment: Hi BalusC i try with 2.1-SNAPSHOT but i have the same error

Comment: I reproduced it and nailed down it being caused by declared inside <cc:implementation> itself instead of outside via <o:validator for>. I fixed it as per [this commit](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/a0884acb1bb519ae9c710b07bd1a5f389e585636). Can you retry today's 2.1-SNAPSHOT and let me know?

Comment: With this new snapshot is working fine , Thanks Baulsc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting `<o:validator>` directly inside `<cc:implementation>` had due to a logic bug the undesired side effect that a new instance of the validator is attached during render response of a postback (because it was expected that the `<o:validator>` was nested inside `<my:composite>` with the `for` attribute). JSF noticed this dynamic change and wanted to save it in the JSF view state so it could be restored on next postback, but it wasn't serializable and hence this exception.

The [fix](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/a0884acb1bb519ae9c710b07bd1a5f389e585636) was simply to not re-attach it at all when already directly inside a composite component. It will be in OmniFaces 2.1.